# CheckColumn in StringGrid

Tags: delphi-xe, firemonkey

Как программно заполнить(выставить чеки) поле CheckColumn из Базы данных? Использую SQLite и поле Status INTEGER. В примере от Embarcadero делается с Visual Bind. Никаких SetCheck или isCheck не нашел в доступных свойствах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще.

```
Grid.Cells[c,i] := 'True';
```